# inherit a remote origin in git

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I read a series of articles on Git, and this term appeared to me, and I did not understand what it meant:
"remote origin"

This is the context in which it appeared:
"If your clone didn't inherit a remote origin, or if you choose to add one later, use the git remote command:"

```
$ git remote add seth@example.com:~/myproject.Git
```

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: That should be `git remote add origin <url>`, not `git remote add <url>`. You have to provide the *name* of the "remote". The word *remote* here is a technical term; it should be defined separately in [the gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary), but instead is left as something you have to infer. At its most basic, it's just a name that lets you store a URL, so that you don't have to type the URL ever again.

Comment: Meanwhile, the name `origin` is simply the standard first name that everyone uses for their first (and usually only) remote.